# Wireless NRF24L01 chip compatibility

Tags: wireless, transceiver, nrf24l01

I have ordered a set of transceiver with NRF24L01 from various vendors. (with and without external antenna)

http://www.ebay.com/itm/NRF24L01-PA-LNA-SMA-Antenna-Wireless-Transceiver-communication-module-2-4G-1100m-/310651702557?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item485448cd1d

http://www.ebay.com/itm/K1BO-4pcs-NRF24L01-2-4GHz-Antenna-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-for-Arduino-New-/271336954345?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item3f2cf159e9

Are they all compatible?

It tells that it supports 1 to 6 communication? But will transmitters from different vendors work with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are compatible. The functionality is determined by the chip, not by the surrounding components.

With some care the NRF24L01 is also compatible with the NRF24L01+, RF70, and RF73.

"It tells that it supports 1 to 6 communication? " - is that a question? - Yes, they all support 1:N communication (in datagram mode - no acknowledging/retransmission). They also support 6 receive 'channels' per chip.

Comment: Main question was first part of your answer. Thank You!